# typo3 plugin with non-editable tables

Tags: typo3

I want to create a Typo3 plugin that can be used as a content type on pages (i.e. FE plugin), without any user input. The plugin would generate content from additional tables in the typo3 database. The content for these tables is inserted outside of typo3.

From what I understand, I have to do the following:

- `ext_tables.php`: The TCA configuration is used for configuring how fields can be edited in the Back End. Since the user must not enter any data, I will not need this
- `ext_tables.sql`: Write the CREATE statements for my tables. This will update the typo3 database and keep it in synch with this definition on updates

Are there any other configuration files I have to edit?

What about views? Does Typo3 understand CREATE VIEW statements in the ext_table.sql?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't need to create a table for your extension you don't need to worry about linking them up on ext_tables.php. I would just write your code into the pi1.php file, querying the desired table and outputting the result.

The file where your code sits is usually on
pi1/class.tx_myextension_pi1.php

Comment: Actually I do need some 30+ tables for my extension, but they are only queried at the front end for display. They do not need to be changed the back end, or even be visible. However, the Database Analyzer in the admin tools should not consider them for dropping...

Comment: Then you just need to have the CREATE statements in the **ext_tables.sql** as that's what controls database modifications in the analyzer. You can omit any TCA configuration which only controls the look and behaviour of the backend forms for your tables which you don't need.